# How to slide a VBox open and close in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I've got a splitpane with items and children, leftPane, ContentPane and RigthPane. I want to click on leftPane and have the pane closed while ContentPane takes over the space. Upon another click I want the pane to slide open to original position, so ContentPane should shrink back to normal.

I manage to create the closing effect by setting the "leftPane.setMaxWidth(0);" but somehow I can not revert the process "leftPane.setMaxWidth(200);" on the fadeIn method:

Any Idea How I can make it work?

```
        <SplitPane>
    <items>
        <VBox fx:id="leftPane" styleClass="resizable-vbox" onMousePressed="#handleMousePressed" onMouseReleased="#handleMouseReleased">
            <children>
                <Label text="Domain 1" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <AnchorPane>
            <VBox fx:id="contentPane" styleClass="resizable-vbox_content">
                <children>
                    <Label text="Domain 2" />
                </children>
            </VBox>
        </AnchorPane>
        <VBox fx:id="rightPane" styleClass="resizable-vbox">
            <children>
                <Label text="Domain 3" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </items>
</SplitPane>
```

In the controller I've got:

```
 @FXML
private void handleMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    if (leftPaneVisible) {
        fadeOutVBox();
    } else {
        fadeInVBox();
    }
    leftPaneVisible = !leftPaneVisible;
    adjustCenterPane();
}

 private void fadeInVBox() {
    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3));
    ft.setNode(leftPane);
    ft.setFromValue(0);
    ft.setToValue(1);
    ft.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            leftPane.setMaxWidth(200);// Does not restore VBox size.
            leftPaneVisible = true;                
        }
    });
    ft.play();
    
}

private void fadeOutVBox() {
    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.3));
    ft.setNode(leftPane);
    ft.setFromValue(1);
    ft.setToValue(0);
    ft.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            leftPane.setMaxWidth(0);//gives me the desired effect.
            leftPaneVisible = false;               
        }
    });
    ft.play();
}

private void adjustCenterPane() {
    double leftPaneWidth = leftPaneVisible ? leftPane.getPrefWidth() : 0;
    double rightPaneWidth = rightPane.isVisible() ? rightPane.getWidth() : 0;
    double parentWidth = contentPane.getParent().getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    double contentPaneWidth = parentWidth - leftPaneWidth - rightPaneWidth;

    contentPane.setPrefWidth(contentPaneWidth);
}
```

and this is my style.css:

```
        .resizable-vbox {
    -fx-background-color: lightgreen;
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 120px;
    -fx-min-width: 10px;
    -fx-max-width: 200px;
}


.right-pane {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
    -fx-min-width: 100px;
    -fx-max-width: 400px;
}
.resizable-vbox_content {
    -fx-background-color: lightgray;
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
    -fx-min-width: 100px;
    -fx-max-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As there can be more than one approach for a solution, below is my version :)

Below is a demo of a class that does the sliding effect. I believe you can try for the other directions if required.

If you need more details about the approach, I have written a [blog](https://blog.e-zest.com/sliding-in-javafx-its-all-about-clipping/) explaining the concept of clipping for sliding (very old blog, but still relatable ;-).

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class SlidingPaneDemo extends Application {
    private Rectangle2D boxBounds;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        buildRoot(root);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Sliding Pane Demo");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void buildRoot(HBox root) {
        final TreeView<String> contentInSliding = new TreeView<>();
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        populateChild(rootItem, 1);
        contentInSliding.setRoot(rootItem);

        final SlidingContainer slidingContainer = new SlidingContainer(contentInSliding, "<<", "Show TreeView");
        root.getChildren().addAll(slidingContainer, buildContentPane());
    }

    private GridPane buildContentPane() {
        GridPane content = new GridPane();
        content.setHgap(5);
        content.setVgap(5);
        content.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        HBox.setHgrow(content, Priority.ALWAYS);

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setMaxWidth(180);
        content.addRow(0, new Label("Location"), tf);
        StackPane c = new StackPane(new Label("Content"));
        c.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#fefefe;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-width:1px;");
        content.add(c, 0, 1, 2, 1);

        ColumnConstraints c1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints c2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        c2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        content.getColumnConstraints().addAll(c1, c2);

        RowConstraints r1 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints r2 = new RowConstraints();
        r2.setVgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        content.getRowConstraints().addAll(r1, r2);
        return content;
    }

    private void populateChild(TreeItem<String> r, int level) {
        if (level > 3) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> itm = new TreeItem<>("Item " + i + "-" + level);
            itm.setExpanded(true);
            populateChild(itm, level + 1);
            r.getChildren().add(itm);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Container Pane that slides to hide or show.
     */
    class SlidingContainer extends HBox {

        private String hideMessage;
        private String showMessage;

        public SlidingContainer(Region node, String hideMessage, String showMessage) {
            this.hideMessage = hideMessage;
            this.showMessage = showMessage;
            StackPane slidingContainer = new StackPane(node);

            Label direction = new Label(hideMessage);
            direction.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;");
            direction.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
            direction.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            StackPane bar = new StackPane(direction);
            bar.setMaxWidth(20);
            bar.setMinWidth(20);
            bar.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#777777;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-border-width:0px 1px;");
            bar.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);

            node.widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                if (boxBounds == null) {
                    slidingContainer.setPrefWidth(node.getWidth());
                    boxBounds = new Rectangle2D(0, 0, node.getWidth(), node.getHeight());
                    setClip(slidingContainer, node, bar, direction);
                }
            });

            getChildren().addAll(slidingContainer, bar);
        }

        private void setClip(StackPane container, Region node, StackPane bar, Label direction) {
            Rectangle clipRect = new Rectangle();
            clipRect.heightProperty().bind(node.heightProperty());
            clipRect.setWidth(boxBounds.getWidth());
            node.setClip(clipRect);

            // Animation for bouncing effect.
            final Timeline timelineBounce = new Timeline();
            timelineBounce.setCycleCount(2);
            timelineBounce.setAutoReverse(true);
            final KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(clipRect.widthProperty(), 15);
            final KeyValue kv2 = new KeyValue(container.prefWidthProperty(), 15);
            final KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), kv1, kv2);
            timelineBounce.getKeyFrames().add(kf1);
            timelineBounce.setOnFinished(e -> {

            });

            // Event handler to call bouncing effect after the scroll down is finished.
            EventHandler onFinished = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    direction.setText(showMessage);
                    direction.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-font-size:16px;");
                    direction.setRotate(-90);
                    timelineBounce.play();
                }
            };

            Timeline timelineHide = new Timeline();
            timelineHide.setCycleCount(1);
            timelineHide.setAutoReverse(true);
            final KeyValue kvHide1 = new KeyValue(clipRect.widthProperty(), 0);
            final KeyValue kvHide2 = new KeyValue(container.prefWidthProperty(), 0);
            final KeyFrame kfHide = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), onFinished, kvHide1, kvHide2);
            timelineHide.getKeyFrames().add(kfHide);

            Timeline timelineShow = new Timeline();
            timelineShow.setCycleCount(1);
            timelineShow.setAutoReverse(true);
            final KeyValue kvShow1 = new KeyValue(clipRect.widthProperty(), boxBounds.getWidth());
            final KeyValue kvShow2 = new KeyValue(container.prefWidthProperty(), boxBounds.getWidth());
            final KeyFrame kfShow = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), kvShow1, kvShow2);
            timelineShow.setOnFinished(e -> {
                direction.setText(hideMessage);
                direction.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;");
                direction.setRotate(0);
            });
            timelineShow.getKeyFrames().add(kfShow);

            bar.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (direction.getText().equals("<<")) {
                    timelineHide.play();
                } else {
                    timelineShow.play();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on a `Hamburger` but have not completed it. Here is the code I have so far. Maybe it can help you. Pressing the `Hamburger` menu opens a sliding `StackPane`.

---

**Test App Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vbHeader = new VBox();
         
        StackPane spBody = new StackPane(getMainView());
        spBody.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        VBox.setVgrow(spBody, Priority.ALWAYS);
        StackPaneRoot hamburger = new StackPaneRoot(spBody, StackPaneRoot.Location.LEFT);
        hamburger.setDrawerContent(getDrawerContent());
        hamburger.setDrawerMaxWidth(150);
        hamburger.setDrawerDurationMillis(500);
        
        vbHeader.getChildren().add(hamburger);
        
        
        
        VBox root = new VBox(vbHeader, spBody);
        var scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public StackPane getMainView()
    {
        Label lblOne = new Label("One");
       
        
        VBox vBox = new VBox(lblOne);        
        
        return new StackPane(vBox);
    }
    
    public VBox getDrawerContent()
    {
        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        Button btnDelete = new Button("Delete");
        Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
        Button btnStop = new Button("Stop");
        Button btnPlaceHolding = new Button();
        Button btnLogOff = new Button("Log Off");
        
        
        return new VBox(btnAdd, btnDelete, btnStart, btnStop, btnPlaceHolding, btnLogOff);
    }   
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

---

**Hamburger Class**

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.codicons.Codicons;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class StackPaneRoot extends ToggleButton
{
    public static enum Location{
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        BOTTOM
    }
    
    private final static FontIcon THREE_BARS_ICON = new FontIcon(Codicons.THREE_BARS);
    private final static FontIcon CHROME_CLOSE_ICON = new FontIcon(Codicons.CHROME_CLOSE);
        
    public double drawerMaxWidth = 100;
    public double drawerMaxHeight = 100;
    public double drawerAnimationDurationMillis = 300;
    
    KeyFrame showKeyFrame;
    KeyFrame hideKeyFrame;
    Location location;
    
    StackPane spParent;

    final StackPane drawer = new StackPane();
    
    public StackPaneRoot(StackPane rootParent, Location location){     
        this.spParent = (StackPane)rootParent;
        this.location = location;            
        this.drawer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");                 

        setValues(); 
    }   
    
    public void setDrawerContent(Parent parent)
    {
        this.drawer.getChildren().clear();
        this.drawer.getChildren().add(parent);
    }
    
    public void setDrawerMaxWidth(double drawerMaxWidth)
    {
        this.drawerMaxWidth = drawerMaxWidth;
        setValues();    
    }
    
    public void setDrawerMaxHeight(double drawerMaxHeight)
    {
        this.drawerMaxHeight = drawerMaxHeight;
        setValues();
    }
    
    public void setDrawerDurationMillis(double drawerAnimationDurationMillis)
    {
        this.drawerAnimationDurationMillis = drawerAnimationDurationMillis;
        setValues();
    }
    
    
    
    private void setValues()
    {
        switch(this.location)
        {
            case LEFT:                   
                StackPane.setAlignment(this.drawer, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                showKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateXProperty(), 0));
                hideKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateXProperty(), -drawerMaxWidth));
                this.drawer.setMaxWidth(drawerMaxWidth);
                this.drawer.setTranslateX(-drawerMaxWidth);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                StackPane.setAlignment(this.drawer, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                showKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateXProperty(), 0));
                hideKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateXProperty(), drawerMaxWidth));
                this.drawer.setMaxWidth(drawerMaxWidth);
                this.drawer.setTranslateX(drawerMaxWidth);
                break;                    
            case BOTTOM:
                StackPane.setAlignment(this.drawer, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
                showKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateYProperty(), 0));
                hideKeyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(drawerAnimationDurationMillis), new KeyValue(this.drawer.translateYProperty(), drawerMaxHeight));
                this.drawer.setMaxHeight(drawerMaxHeight);
                this.drawer.setTranslateY(drawerMaxHeight);
                break;
        }
        
        Timeline show = new Timeline(showKeyFrame);             
        Timeline hide = new Timeline(hideKeyFrame);
        
        this.setGraphic(THREE_BARS_ICON);
        this.setOnAction((t) -> {
            this.setDisable(true);
            if(!this.isSelected())
            {                
                this.setGraphic(THREE_BARS_ICON);
                hide.play();
                hide.setOnFinished(onFinishedEvent -> {
                    this.setDisable(false);
                    this.drawer.toBack();
                    this.spParent.getChildren().remove(this.drawer);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                this.drawer.toFront();
                this.spParent.getChildren().add(this.drawer);
                this.setGraphic(CHROME_CLOSE_ICON);
                show.play();
                show.setOnFinished(onFinishedEvent -> {
                    this.setDisable(false);
                });                
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

---

**module-info.java**

```
module sed.lab.hamburgertest {
    requires javafx.controls;    
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.codicons;
    
    exports sed.lab.hamburgertest;
}
```

---

**Output**

[image]